# Encountering error when using update trigger with transactional replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-replication

I'm using transactional replication with updatable subscription.
 when I add a trigger for update in one of my tables which is chosen for replication in publisher, I encounter with this error:

```
Maximum stored procedure, function,trigger, 
or view nesting level exceeded(limit 32)
```

My trigger code is

```
create trigger Isupdated 
    on tbl_worker 
    for update as 
        update tbl_worker SET 
           Isup=1 
        where id= (select id from inserted)
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've written a [recursive (aka nested) trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190739.aspx).

Perhaps the trigger is causing an update on the table, causing the trigger to be fired again?

If you post the code, that would help us explain exactly what the issue is.

Comment: yes my trigger doing an update.because I need to do an update on my records before replicating. I added my query in the last of trigger which is replication created and my problem solved.Am I doing right?

Comment: Um, well, from that it sounds like you have multiple triggers being fired for the original update, thus it's likely you have a indirect-recursion. This can be brittle code, and it's possible you will face this issue again. I would try and simplify your use of triggers if possible, as it sounds like your code is currently too complicated.

Comment: My code is not complicated, I'm just doing and update in one of my fields in update trigger.I'm doing replication on tbl_worker. and this is my code:`create trigger Isupdated on tbl_worker for update as update tbl_worker set Isup=1 where id=(select id from inserted)`

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sqlmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/sql-server-programming/4752/Maximum-stored-procedure-function-trigger-or-view

The above link provides a solution to trigger nesting. This can be very helpful when you already have a trigger and then replication adds another one. I like this more than combining the triggers because it doesn't force you to mix code related to functionality and code related to replication.

To sum up the solution:

You can prevent the nested firing from happening by assigning the triggers
an order with sp_settriggerorder and add the following check to the
beginning of the trigger you set to fire first to prevent it being fired by
the other trigger:

CREATE TRIGGER....
IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL > 1 RETURN